# Spring boot application startup classloading issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hateoas

Recently I was going through a tutorial from [spring.io on HATEOAS][1]

I followed all the steps in setting up the project and verified the dependencies as well. But unable to fix the issue when I start to boot the application. Here is the debug logs when i launch the application by doing "java -jar hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

> Error logs

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at bookmarks.Application.main(Application.java:14) [hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:195) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1170) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:77) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

> 

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170) ~[hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142) ~[hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:45) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:41) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.<clinit>(HibernatePersistence.java:46) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:177) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:84) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.getProviders(Persistence.java:69) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.access$000(Persistence.java:23) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:109) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1612) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1597) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:609) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:524) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:492) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:407) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/:5.2.4.Final]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:350) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:271) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178) ~[hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142) ~[hateoas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
            ... 104 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code
```

There seems to be a conflict on how Spring Boot discovers dependencies.

> mvn dependency:tree

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] bookmarks
    [INFO] model
    [INFO] rest
    [INFO] security
    [INFO] hateoas
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building bookmarks 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ bookmarks ---
    [INFO] bookmarks:bookmarks:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
    [INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.0.0:test
    [INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.1.1:test
    [INFO] |     \- net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0.2:test
    [INFO] |        \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:test
    [INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:test
    [INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
    [INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
    [INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
    [INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
    [INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
    [INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:test
```

> hateoas module

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ hateoas ---
[INFO] bookmarks:hateoas:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.19.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- bookmarks:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.191:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
```

Looking for a solution to resolve this conflict.

Comment: Please replace the link to the snapshot with the pom.xml and the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: i've replaced the link to pom.xml as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code

To me this sounds like your hibernate-core dependency containing `org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger` is corrupted. Delete and reload it.

If it's not about that, then your .jar building got broken. As it's probably not a problem with actual build code, it could be a problem of the hard drive.

Comment: May be but wasn't able to figure out the issue as its going over my head. I tried to delete some of the cached dependencies from .m2 repository to see if that helps but that lead me to someother issue. But I tried the same project on a different machine and it worked with no issues.

Comment: @Franky if that lead to another issue, isn't that a signal that this was part of the problem? Another issue would need another question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I wasn't sure about the internal mechanics of maven repository or hard drive.